# Macbook Pro 2015 continuously powered on

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

As it is slowly aging, I'm starting to consider leaving it continuously powered on.

Currently it stays most of the day powered on, for about the past six months.

Recently I noticed that its bottom is slightly bent. I have used it carefully through all of its life, taking good care not to over expose it to high temperatures.

**Does leaving it continuously powered on entail any risk of catastrophic explosion, or further bending?**

Comment: Are you sure the bending isn't the result of an aging battery?

Comment: Hmmm. Because my cousin has, or had, a contemporary 15-inch Macbook Pro (Retina), his has been bent for years, and he is a physicist instead of a computer scientist. That's the reason I thought the cause would have been a thermal exposition.

Comment: @uprego You need to have your battery checked and replaced - don't wait with it. It has nothing to do with it the case expanding because you're overusing the fans. It has to do with a defective battery that swells up, and potentially could lead to a dangerous situation if left unattended.

Comment: It's on its way now. :)

Comment: I just received the machine unbent and supposedly there’s a new battery now. :)

Comment: It seems to be right. Lower case remembers a bit of the bending, I think, but now it sits perfectly, clearly, on the four rubber _legs_. Now it's clean, and looks awesome, as if was brand new. Still claims to be mounted 16GB of memory and 1TB of storage. I think they said keyboard is also new because the piece is the same. Unfortunately, I asked them to... supposing keyboard had to be changed, then replace the ISO country customised keyboard for an US ANSI keyboard, but they sadly rejected that possibility. I'll move the data back from the back ups and the other machine I used in the interim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in almost all cases caused by the battery swelling up and thus "bending" the case. The case expansion cannot in itself be caused by "overuse of fans".

You need to have your battery checked and replaced - don't wait with it. It is caused by a defective battery that swells up, and potentially could lead to a dangerous situation (such as causing a fire) if left unattended. This can happen not only when the computer is plugged in and powered - but also when the computer is turned off and not powered by an external power source!

Remember that the battery is a wearing part, and yours is probably 4+ years by now.

Comment: and by dangerous situation we mean the *possibility* of fire or in some cases explosion. Not trying to scare you but I would have this checked **NOW**

Comment: Alright, alright, I mean, I thought the case expansion was caused by excessive temperature on the battery, not because overusing fans. So what should I do? Bring the laptop to the Apple Store (I live in a big city)? Once replacing the battery, what should I do in order to repair the bent case?

Comment: @uprego It's not in general caused by excessive temperature on the battery, no. The batteries are specced to be able to withstand the temperatures found inside the MacBook Pro - even if you run the fans all the time. The most common causes of swelling are really mechanical damage (i.e. for example if you drop or bump the laptop, but could also be during shipping/manufacturing), faulty charging electronics (i.e. overcharging), very intensive use of the battery (i.e. fully discharging it often) and simply old age. I would say that you shouldn't expect laptop batteries to last more than 3 years

Comment: I.e. it's not that laptop batteries cannot last more than 3 years, but after that point, I wouldn't be surprised if something happened and it had to be replaced. Also ofcourse, temperature can play a part in it too - but then it would usually be from outside sources - i.e. if you leave the laptop in the sun for hours.

Comment: I'll ask hardware technical support folk, but I suspect of the fact contemporary macOS has not protested about the battery aging, unlike iOS does as soon as iOS version 12. 

Comment: @uprego You couldn’t really be farther off - no, that’s not the case. iOS 12 does not “protect” against aging (as in prevent aging) more than the previous versions.

Comment: Your last comment seems to imply **every** battery such old is aged. Which contradicts a previous claim of yours.

Comment: @uprego You're not really making sense to me now. Would you care to explain? ... There's nothing in macOS that makes it "wear out" batteries faster than for example an iPhone (if you can even compare that). There's no missing "anti age" software component or anything like that. I haven't said that "all batteries are aged", that doesn't make sense. But in general, all these batteries age with time (obviously). Doesn't matter if its a laptop battery or an iPhone battery. I don't know what claims you're referring to.

Comment: Note to self: delete this question if I ever have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @uprego Odd to want to delete it? - Am I misunderstanding something here - did you not get your question answered? Is it something else you seek, or do you think we're overlooking something? I would rather get you an answer you're happy with rather than having the question deleted, so that others with similar problems cannot find help.

Comment: You took a statement, where I state that my OS is not warning that the battery is aging, and twisted it as if I had wrote that software can prevent battery aging. There are only three possible actions against that: close Stack Exchange account, or delete post (or if not possible, add a note to self in order to delete once possible), or take a day off before writing anything again.

Comment: You’re really overreacting now. You wrote that the system does not “protest”, due to the choice of word I thought you meant “protect”. I understand now that you meant “report”. You could just let me know that you didn’t mean protect, and I could have helped you with software that reports battery status. Indeed macOS already by default will warn you when the battery is too old and needs replacement. There’s really no need to delete your Stack Exchange Account

Comment: And by the way - just so you know that it is not a twisted statement - software can in fact prevent battery aging!

Comment: Alright, happy to understand you now. I've backed up my data, twice, I'm now shredding where the data was in the laptop, and tomorrow I'll be meeting with official tech support.

Comment: Remember that because your laptop has an SSD, the data will not be fully deleted when trashing and shredding. For that to work you’ll to be using File Vault.

Comment: I just did `find /PATH/TO/MY/DATA/ -type f -exec shred -u {} \; && rm -rf /PATH/TO/MY/DATA/*`, now the computer is in their repair pipeline.

Comment: shred doesn't work on SSDs, that's what I meant. It is designed for spinning disks.

Comment: Too bad, I tested some directory before removing the bulk, without `-u` (no `r`e`m`oval), probed them from `vim`, docs contents seemed to get overwritten with some sort of pseudo random garbage. Seemed good enough. :(

Comment: @uprego Yes, that's the way it works. However that's not the same as the data being fully gone from the SSD. If you have to be compliant with GDPR, HIPAA or similar, you might want to do more.

Comment: Personal data of mine. No special compliance needed. By the way, at Apple's I signed them a paper that they agree repair in case of data related damages involving dolum (in Europe, if that's significant).

Comment: I don’t understand you unfortunately - I assume you mean “malicious intent” with dolum perhaps? But anyways, if it is your own personal data, then you’re free to do with it as you like.